# Promises with cheerio and axios - nested for loop inside

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

I am **scraping** a website similar to craiglist.

My main target is to build and object like this (example for car advertising):

```
{ title: 'VOLKSWAGEN',
    cv: '75 cv',
    model: 'POLO 1. 0 ADVANCE',
    brand: 'Volkswagen',
    place: 'Malpaso Buzanada ( Arona )',
    location: 'Tenerife',
    transmision: 'manual',
    fuel: 'gasolina',
    km: '90.000 kms',
    year: '2016',
    doors: '5 puertas',
    description:
     'Test description',
    vendor: 'Profesional',
    reference: 'r343187239',
    price: '7.799',
    type: 'OFERTA',
    image:
     [ 'https://img.website.com/fg/3431/87/343187239_1.jpg',
       'https://img.website.com/fg/3431/87/343187239_2.jpg',
       'https://img.website.com/fg/3431/87/343187239_3.jpg',
       'https://img.website.com/fg/3431/87/343187239_4.jpg' ] }
```

It will be an array of this king of objects, with every ad I get from this website.

My problem is that I can reach this array of objects, but I can handle it for save images in disk after I created.

I think am doing something wrong with promises:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const axios = require('axios');
const $ = require('cheerio', { decodeEntities: true });

const url = 'https://www.website.com/anuncios/700000000.htm';

const adArray = [];

const axiosData = axios.get(url,{responseType: 'arraybuffer',responseEncoding: 'binary'})
    .then(result => {
        const myP = $('.aditem', result.data.toString('binary')).each((i, element) => {
            function checkCVinTitle (cv, model) {
                const cvNoSpace = cv.replace(' ', '');
                if(model){
                    if(model.includes(cv.toUpperCase())) {
                        createAdObject.model = model.replace(cv.toUpperCase(),''); 
                    } 
                    else if(model.includes(cvNoSpace.toUpperCase())){
                        createAdObject.model = model.replace(cvNoSpace.toUpperCase(),''); 
                    }
                    else {
                        // console.log('no model')
                    }
                    return createAdObject.model;
                }
            }
            const capitalize = (str, lower = false) =>
            (lower ? str.toLowerCase() : str).replace(/(?:^|\s|["'([{])+\S/g, match => match.toUpperCase());
                
                const createAdObject = {};
                // cheerio variables for each parameter
                const titleAndModel = $('.aditem-detail-title', element).text();
                const brandAndPlace = $('.display-desktop.list-location-link', element).text();
                const cv = $('.cc.tag-mobile', element).text();
                const location = $('.list-location-region', element).text();
                const transmision = $('.cmanual.tag-mobile', element).text();
                const fuel = $('.gas.tag-mobile', element).text();
                const km = $('.kms.tag-mobile', element).text();
                const year = $('.ano.tag-mobile', element).text();
                const doors = $('.ejes.tag-mobile', element).text();
                const description = $('.tx', element).text();
                const price = $('.aditem-price', element).text();
                const vendor = $('.pillDiv.pillSellerTypePro', element).text();
                const reference = $('.x5', element).text();
                const type = $('.x3', element).text();

                    createAdObject.title = titleAndModel.split(' - ')[0];
                    createAdObject.cv = cv;
                    createAdObject.model = titleAndModel.split(' - ')[1];
                    checkCVinTitle(cv, createAdObject.model);
                    createAdObject.brand = brandAndPlace.split(' de segunda mano en ')[0];
                    createAdObject.place = brandAndPlace.split(' de segunda mano en ')[1];
                    createAdObject.location = capitalize(location);
                    createAdObject.transmision = transmision;
                    createAdObject.fuel = fuel;
                    createAdObject.km = km;
                    createAdObject.year = year.split(' ')[1]
                    createAdObject.doors = doors;
                    createAdObject.description = description.replace('\n', ' ');
                    createAdObject.vendor = vendor;
                    createAdObject.reference = reference.replace(/\s/g,'');
                    createAdObject.price = price.replace('€', '');
                    createAdObject.type = type;
                    createAdObject.image = [];
                    // function generate array images
                        let promises = [];
                        const averageImage = 5;
                        for(let i=1; i < averageImage; i++){
                            const image = `https://img.website.com/fg/${createAdObject.reference.slice(1,5)}/${createAdObject.reference.slice(5,7)}/${createAdObject.reference.substr(1)}_${i}.jpg`;
                            promises.push(axios.get(image)
                                .then(response => {
                                    // response.status == 200 ? createAdObject.image.push(image) : console.log('something wrong with images')
                                    response.status == 200 ? createAdObject.image.push(image) : ''
                                    })
                                .catch(error => console.log())
                            )
                        }
                        return Promise.all(promises)
                        .then(() => {
                            type == 'OFERTA' ? createAdObject.brand != 'Scooters' ? adArray.push(createAdObject)  : '' : '';
                            console.log('hey3')
                        })
                        .catch(error => console.log(error))
        })
        return Promise.all([myP])
        .then(() => console.log('hey2'))
    })
    return Promise.all([axiosData])
    .then(() => console.log('hey'))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

I have tried making this with no variable:

```
$('.aditem', result.data.toString('binary')).each((i, element) => {
```

When i run the script, it output this:

```
hey2
hey



hey3
hey3
hey3
hey3
hey3
hey3
hey3
```

I modified returns too, but nothing seem to work for me.

Why is not waiting this promise.all ?

return Promise.all([axiosData])

Is something about cheerio that can't make the foreach waiting for promises?

UPDATE suggested:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const axios = require('axios');
const $ = require('cheerio', { decodeEntities: true });

const url = 'https://www.website.com/ads/700000000.htm';

const adArray = [];

const axiosData = axios.get(url,{responseType: 'arraybuffer',responseEncoding: 'binary'})
    .then(result => {
        const theMap = $('.aditem', result.data.toString('binary')).map(element => {
            function checkCVinTitle (cv, model) {
                const cvNoSpace = cv.replace(' ', '');
                if(model){
                    if(model.includes(cv.toUpperCase())) {
                        createAdObject.model = model.replace(cv.toUpperCase(),''); 
                    } 
                    else if(model.includes(cvNoSpace.toUpperCase())){
                        createAdObject.model = model.replace(cvNoSpace.toUpperCase(),''); 
                    }
                    else {
                        // console.log('no model')
                    }
                    return createAdObject.model;
                }
            }
            const capitalize = (str, lower = false) =>
            (lower ? str.toLowerCase() : str).replace(/(?:^|\s|["'([{])+\S/g, match => match.toUpperCase());
                
                const createAdObject = {};
                // cheerio variables for each parameter
                const titleAndModel = $('.aditem-detail-title', element).text();
                const brandAndPlace = $('.display-desktop.list-location-link', element).text();
                const cv = $('.cc.tag-mobile', element).text();
                const location = $('.list-location-region', element).text();
                const transmision = $('.cmanual.tag-mobile', element).text();
                const fuel = $('.gas.tag-mobile', element).text();
                const km = $('.kms.tag-mobile', element).text();
                const year = $('.ano.tag-mobile', element).text();
                const doors = $('.ejes.tag-mobile', element).text();
                const description = $('.tx', element).text();
                const price = $('.aditem-price', element).text();
                const vendor = $('.pillDiv.pillSellerTypePro', element).text();
                const reference = $('.x5', element).text();
                const type = $('.x3', element).text();
                // const image = $('img', element)[0].attribs.src
                // const numberImages = $('.mini-overlay-superior', element).text();

                    createAdObject.title = titleAndModel.split(' - ')[0];
                    createAdObject.cv = cv;
                    createAdObject.model = titleAndModel.split(' - ')[1];
                    checkCVinTitle(cv, createAdObject.model);
                    createAdObject.brand = brandAndPlace.split(' de segunda mano en ')[0];
                    createAdObject.place = brandAndPlace.split(' de segunda mano en ')[1];
                    createAdObject.location = capitalize(location);
                    createAdObject.transmision = transmision;
                    createAdObject.fuel = fuel;
                    createAdObject.km = km;
                    createAdObject.year = year.split(' ')[1]
                    createAdObject.doors = doors;
                    createAdObject.description = description.replace('\n', ' ');
                    createAdObject.vendor = vendor;
                    createAdObject.reference = reference.replace(/\s/g,'');
                    createAdObject.price = price.replace('€', '');
                    createAdObject.type = type;
                    createAdObject.image = [];
                    // function generate array images
                        let promises = []
                        const averageImage = 5;
                        for(let i=1; i < averageImage; i++){
                            const image = `https://img.milanuncios.com/fg/${createAdObject.reference.slice(1,5)}/${createAdObject.reference.slice(5,7)}/${createAdObject.reference.substr(1)}_${i}.jpg`;
                                promises.push(axios.get(image)
                                    .then(response => {
                                        response.status == 200 ? createAdObject.image.push(image) : ''
                                    })
                                    .catch(error => console.log())
                                )
                        }
                        return Promise.all(promises)
                        .then(() => {
                            type == 'OFERTA' ? createAdObject.brand != 'Scooters' ? adArray.push(createAdObject)  : '' : '';
                        })
        })
        Promise.all([theMap])
        .then(console.log(adArray))
    })
    Promise.all([axiosData])
    .then(() => console.log(adArray))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Comment: .each returns void doesnt it? Thus myP is undefined

Comment: problem is, return Promise.all([myP]) not wait for return Promise.all(promises), and last promise return Promise.all([axiosData]) doesn't wait for both of them. Look at the output please.

Comment: myP is not a promise - it is undefined. What is there to wait for. Dont expect Promise.all to be wrong. *Look at the output please*. It tells you there is nothing to wait for in undefined. Use an iterator that actually returns other than undefined. Reduce noise by replacing those long assignments with well named functions. Replace callback functionblocks with well named functions. It will help you understand your code and output.

Comment: I meaning the order. It should be hey3...hey3 and after that, hey2, hey for reach what i am looking for. I am pretty new coding, i am looking for promise as I wrote, not async functions wichs I never face it before.

Comment: yes it is still just that $.each returns undefined - what you want is something that returns the Promise.all(promises) so that you then can wait for it in Promise.all(myP). Thus use $.map! ... async await is just sugar for promises -> const result = await PROMISE is equal to PROMISE.then(result => ...) just better to read

Comment: I tried, and it doesn't work. Before I add image code lines, it works, I got adArray in last promise. I really don't know what I am doing wrong, let me check again as you said but right now it doesn't work for me. Thank you anyway for your time

Comment: Oh that might be because you check ´type== 'OFERTA'´ instead ´createAdObject.type=='OFERTA'´ ;)

Comment: I tried, It doesn't work. I updated as you said. Output => [ ] [ ] (and after it enters in Promise.all(promises) checking images

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$(selector).map()` instead of `$(selector).each()`.

`each()` returns `undefined` and `Promise.all` skips all non-promise values (or more precisely, non-thenable values), as shown below.

```
Promise.all([4, "hello", undefined])
.then(() => {
    console.log("done");
});
```

Comment: It doesnt work. Before I included for loop, i recieved it fine, the adArray values in the last the .

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
(async()=>{
    if(type != 'OFERTA') return;
    const result = await axios.get(url,{responseType: 'arraybuffer',responseEncoding: 'binary'})
    // $.map instead $.each as map rtn [] and each rtns undefined
    const adArray = await $('.aditem', result.data.toString('binary')).map( async (index, element) => {
        const createAdObject = adObject(element);
        if(createAdObject.brand == 'Scooters') return;
        const averageImage = 5;
        const promises = Array.from({length: averageImage}, async (_, i) => {
            let image = imageStr(i, createAdObject)
            return axios.get(image)
        })
        const images = await Promise.all(promises)
        createAdObject.image.push(...images)
        return createAdObject
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved with the structure I needed.

(Thanks everybody for comments and time in replying, .`map` was **very** important for understanding!).

This is my code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const axios = require('axios');
const $ = require('cheerio', { decodeEntities: true });

const url = 'https://www.website.com/ads/123telephonenumber.htm';

const adArray = [];

const axiosData = axios.get(url,{responseType: 'arraybuffer',responseEncoding: 'binary'})
    .then(result => {
        $('.aditem', result.data.toString('binary')).map((i,element) => {
            function checkCVinTitle (cv, model) {
                const cvNoSpace = cv.replace(' ', '');
                if(model){
                    if(model.includes(cv.toUpperCase())) {
                        createAdObject.model = model.replace(cv.toUpperCase(),''); 
                    } 
                    else if(model.includes(cvNoSpace.toUpperCase())){
                        createAdObject.model = model.replace(cvNoSpace.toUpperCase(),''); 
                    }
                    else {
                        // console.log('no model')
                    }
                    return createAdObject.model;
                }
            }
            const capitalize = (str, lower = false) =>
            (lower ? str.toLowerCase() : str).replace(/(?:^|\s|["'([{])+\S/g, match => match.toUpperCase());
                
                const createAdObject = {};
                // cheerio variables for each parameter
                const titleAndModel = $('.aditem-detail-title', element).text();
                const brandAndPlace = $('.display-desktop.list-location-link', element).text();
                const cv = $('.cc.tag-mobile', element).text();
                const location = $('.list-location-region', element).text();
                const transmision = $('.cmanual.tag-mobile', element).text();
                const fuel = $('.gas.tag-mobile', element).text();
                const km = $('.kms.tag-mobile', element).text();
                const year = $('.ano.tag-mobile', element).text();
                const doors = $('.ejes.tag-mobile', element).text();
                const description = $('.tx', element).text();
                const price = $('.aditem-price', element).text();
                const vendor = $('.pillDiv.pillSellerTypePro', element).text();
                const reference = $('.x5', element).text();
                const type = $('.x3', element).text();
                // const image = $('img', element)[0].attribs.src
                // const numberImages = $('.mini-overlay-superior', element).text();

                    createAdObject.title = titleAndModel.split(' - ')[0];
                    createAdObject.cv = cv;
                    createAdObject.model = titleAndModel.split(' - ')[1];
                    checkCVinTitle(cv, createAdObject.model);
                    createAdObject.brand = brandAndPlace.split(' de segunda mano en ')[0];
                    createAdObject.place = brandAndPlace.split(' de segunda mano en ')[1];
                    createAdObject.location = capitalize(location);
                    createAdObject.transmision = transmision;
                    createAdObject.fuel = fuel;
                    createAdObject.km = km;
                    createAdObject.year = year.split(' ')[1]
                    createAdObject.doors = doors;
                    createAdObject.description = description.replace('\n', ' ');
                    createAdObject.vendor = vendor;
                    createAdObject.reference = reference.replace(/\s/g,'');
                    createAdObject.price = price.replace('€', '');
                    createAdObject.type = type;
                    createAdObject.image = [];
                    type == 'OFERTA' ? createAdObject.brand != 'Scooters' ? adArray.push(createAdObject)  : '' : '';
        })
    })
    Promise.all([axiosData])
    .then(() => {
        let promises = [];
        const averageImage = 10;
        const fullAdArray = adArray.map( element => {
            for(let i=1; i < averageImage; i++){
                const image = `https://img.website.com/fg/${element.reference.slice(1,5)}/${element.reference.slice(5,7)}/${element.reference.substr(1)}_${i}.jpg`;
                    promises.push(axios.get(image)
                        .then(response => {
                            response.status == 200 ? element.image.push(image) : ''
                        })
                        .catch(error => console.log(error))
                    )
            }
            return Promise.all(promises)
            .then(() => element)
        })
        return Promise.all(fullAdArray);
    })
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
```